# Looking for an intuitive way to compare a factor with character strings in R

Tags: r

String values are sorted by alphabetical order in R, so by default, the character string `small` appears to be "greater than" the character string `moderate` and `huge`:

```r
a <- c("small", "moderate", "huge")
sort(a, decreasing = F)            
#> [1] "huge"     "moderate" "small"
a > "small"                        
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The most reasonable way to change the order of character strings in R is to store them as a factor and specify the levels:

```r
b <- factor(c("small", "moderate", "huge"), levels = c("small", "moderate", "huge"))
sort(b, decreasing = F)                                                             
#> [1] small    moderate huge    
#> Levels: small moderate huge
```

Now, I know of two ways to compare the factor with a character string to get the values greater than `small`:

```r
b %in% c("moderate", "huge")                                                        
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
as.integer(b) > 1                                                                   
#> [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

However, the first way is tedious when there are many levels in a factor, in which case I'll have to list all the qualified levels. On the other hand, the second way is not intuitive.

In PostgreSQL, you can define a `enum` data type, which is similar to `factor` in R, so when you do comparison `b > 'small'`, the result would be `FALSE TRUE TRUE`. But in R, you can't do that:

```r
b > "small"                                                                         
#> Warning in Ops.factor(b, "small"): '>' not meaningful for factors
#> [1] NA NA NA
```

So my question is, is the above kind of operation in R possible with some prerequisites that I am missing; or is there another kind of convenient and intuitive way to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then I think `ordered` gives what you want:

```
x <- ordered(c("small", "moderate", "huge"), levels = c("small", "moderate", "huge"))
x[1] < x[2]
# [1] TRUE
x[1] < x[3]
# [1] TRUE
x[2] < x[3]
# [1] TRUE
```

since

```
x
# [1] small    moderate huge    
# Levels: small < moderate < huge
```

Also we have

```
x[1] < "huge"
# [1] TRUE
x[1] < "huuge"
# [1] NA
```

Indeed, as @NickZeng comments, `ordered` is just a factor with an imposed order between levels (given in an increasing order), and it is a shortcut for `factor` with an option `ordered = TRUE`.

It is also easy to go back from ordered factors to unordered ones: `factor(x)` gives that.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for, thank you! For those curious, `ordered()` is essentially `factor()` with the option `ordered = T`.